# values are not saving into database in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I am trying to save my checkbox value but i dont know where i am wrong i am stuck in this issue 
my controller where i am performing my action:

Controller:

```
public function preferences(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();

    $preference = new Preference();

    $preference->userID = $user;
    $preference->monthly = Input::get('monthly') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->weekly = Input::get('weekly') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->tax_reviews = Input::get('tax_reviews') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->quarterly = Input::get('quarterly') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->quarterly = Input::get('quarterly') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->annually = Input::get('annually') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->newsletter = Input::get('newsletter') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->direct_mail_reviews = Input::get('direct_mail_reviews') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->email = Input::get('email') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->sms = Input::get('sms') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
    $preference->save();

    return back();

}
```

My Form:

```
<form id="preferences_form" role="form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/preference') }}" class="mujucet-registration">
                                <h5>Nastavení zpráv</h5>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label  for="ch1">
                        <input type='hidden' name='monthly' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="monthly" value="1" id="ch1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Měsíční výpisy
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='monthly' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="weekly" value="1" ><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Týdenní přehled
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='tax_reviews' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="tax_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Daňové výpisy
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='quarterly' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="quarterly" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Čtvrtletní výpisy
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='annually' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="annually" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Roční výpisy
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='newsletter' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label class="border">
                        <input type='hidden' name='direct_mail_reviews' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="direct_mail_reviews" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span> Chci výpisy zasílat také Poštou <span class="light">20 kč za výpis</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div><h5>Kontaktní preference</h5>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='email' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Email
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                        <input type='hidden' name='sms' value='0'>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="sms" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>SMS
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>                        </div>
```

My routes

```
Route::post('preference','HomeController@preferences');
```

My model where i am having my database name

```
class Preference extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'db_preferences';

    protected $fillable = ['userID','monthly','weekly','tax_reviews','quarterly','annually','newsletter','direct_mail_reviews','email','sms'];
}
```

i dont know why data is not inserting into database i click the submit button and page refresh and thats it and i am getting no error but data is not saving into db.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here might be missing [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing) token. You should add

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

after

```
<form id="preferences_form" role="form" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ url('/preference') }}" class="mujucet-registration">
```

line

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1: Consider Marcin's Nabiałek answer aswell! Csrf token is missing..

In order to understand what happens and actually learn, check the input(s) you get from the requests before making any changes. Add the command `dd($request->all());` in the first line of the function `preferences()` to see what `inputs` the `$request` holds.

There are two problems.

1) HTML. Since you have

`<input type='checkbox'>`

You don't need the hidden types :

`<input type='hidden'>`

For example instead of :

```
 <input type='hidden' name='newsletter' value='0'>
 <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
```

Change it to (**without the input type because it is no needed**) :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"><span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>Novinky
```

2) Secondly, the controller checks for a value of `on` but the value you put on the checkbox is `1` so it should be changed to :

```
$preference->newsletter = Input::get('newsletter') == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

*If a checkbox value is not set, but the user has checked the checkbox, yes it will return the value `on`

Extra information about case (1) :

You shouldn't have two elements with the same `name`. The actual problem is that you check for a value of `on` but the inputs have a value of `1`. Even though an element with the same name exists twice, the request will be overwritten with the last one (in your case it is overwritten with the input type checkbox). However, in your case, input(s) type hidden should be removed.